# Matrices over field with characteristic $p$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $A,B$ $n\times n $ matrices over a field $F$ with characteristic $p$ if $AB-BA=cI$ for $c\in F$ does this imply that $c=0$?

Intuitively I would say that it doesn't but I cannot think of a counterexample.

By considering the trace we have that $\mathrm{trace}(cI)=0$ so $cn=0$. Since $\mathrm{char}(F)=p$ we have that $p|nc$ so $p|n$ or $p|c$. If $c\neq 0$ then $p|n$. But I couldn't get more than that.

Comment: It does not. There is a standard example with $c = 1$, where $B$ is multiplication by $x$ in the truncated polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^p)$, and $A$ is differentiation wrt $x$ on the same ring.

Comment: @darijgrinberg What would be the matrices in this case? I didn't understand completely.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_p\left[x\right]/\left(x^p\right)$ is a $p$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space with basis formed by the residue classes of the monomials $1$, $x$, $x^2$, ..., $x^{p-1}$. In this basis, $A$ and $B$ are represented by strictly triangular matrices (one is upper-triangular, the other lower-triangular).

Comment: @darijgrinberg For $p=5$ will it be:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&2&0&0\\0&0&0&3&0\\0&0&0&0&4\\0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}

B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}

?
$$

Comment: @user150391 The matrices represent linear operators from the vector space $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^p)$ to itself. The vector space is defined over the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ and the entries of the matrices are also from the same field of course.

Comment: @user150391: Yes.